# Why is Li easiest to oxidise among the alkali metals despite having the greatest ionization energy 1 in the group?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, alkali-metals

If we use the magnitude of the IE1 as an indicator of ease of oxidation, Li is the most difficult of the alkali metals to oxidise. On the other hand, if E0redn (standard reduction electrode potential) is used as the criterion, Li is the easiest to oxidise. How can we explain this discrepancy?

Comment: You should include in questions a short conclusion from prior info searching, so others do not write things you already know, or should know if searched about it. If nothing was found, write at least what you have searched for.  Aside of general keyword search, search also with the search modifier `site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org` to find similar topics on the respective site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First ioanization energy describes the energy needed to take electron from an isolated atom in its gaseous state. However, standard reduction potential describes the tendency of losing or gaining electrons typically in aqueous solution. So in case of the reduction potential you also need to consider 3 different steps that contribute to the calculation of reduction potential:

1. heat of vaporization of the metal (separation of atom in gaseous state from bulk metal in solid)
2. the ionization energy of the atom (removing electron from the atom to create ions)
3. the enthalpy of hydration of the metal ions (turning into aqueous ion by water molecules)

As you pointed out, ionization energy of sodium (495 kJ/mol) is less than lithium (520 kJ/mol) meaning that you would spend less energy to ionize sodium. However, hydration of enthalpy of lithium is -515 kJ/mol while for sodium it is -405 kJ/mol as charge density of lithium ion is higher and its ion size is smaller (that helps with making bond with lone pair of electrons on oxygen atom in water molecule, thus a stronger bond and more energy is released). You can notice that the difference between the hydration entalphies of lithium and sodium is much higher than the difference in ionization energy. So in comparison to lithium it is easier to ionize sodium atoms, however it is much harder to hydrate the sodium ions compared to the lithium ions. That is why aqueous/hydrated lithium ions have less reduction or higher oxidation potentials than aqueous/hydrated sodium ions. In summary, you are "spending" less energy in general to remove electron from bulk lithium metal based on the steps I mentioned before. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

You compare a single formal step (atom ionization) with a multi-step process leading from solid bulk metal to hydrated metal ions.

The higher ionization energy means the higher energy barrier as a kinetic obstacle, so metallic lithium has in general the lower kinetic reactivity in the group I.

But in context of electrochemical processes in water,

- formal metal atomization
- atom ionization
- electron capture by bulk metal
- metal ion hydration

lithium has due high ion hydration enthalpy the most negative change of Gibbs energy. Therefore, it has the most negative reduction potential and the highest thermodynamic reactivity.